# Can anyone plz tell why error is showing in my code its a basic addeventlistener format

Tags: dom-manipulation

```js
var ash=document.querySelector("#button");

ash.addEventListener("click", backi() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  document.body.classList.add("purple");
});
```

VM17:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

You are defining function incorrectly:

```js
var ash = document.querySelector("#button");

ash.addEventListener("click", function () { // You should create lambda function
                                            // with "function () {}"
  console.log("Clicked");
  document.body.classList.add("purple");
});
```

Comment: Thanku Ivan Didyk.(Be lated)